# Pact body matching - match number of nodes

Tags: java, consumer, pact

I try to achieve the following:

I want to verify that a specific node in body ("entry") has between a minimum and a maximum number of direct subnodes called "content" (1 to 10 nodes). I don't care about what is in these subnodes, which value they have or how many subnodes they have.

Since I'm new to pact and don't really know how to match something like this I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit1:

I use a node matcher one of my collegues built like following:

```
return builder.given("given").uponReceiving("description").path(SERVICEPATH)
                .query(query).method(METHOD_GET).headers(ACCEPT, REQ_ACCEPT).willRespondWith().status(200)
                .matchHeader(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, RESP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_REGEX).body(responseBody)
                .matchBody(new PactDslXmlNodeMatcher().node("entry").node("content").value(".*")).toPact();
```

Don't let that irritate you, that `.matchBody` just converts that node to the typical `$. + path + '[#text]'`-notation, where `.value` adds an regex-matcher rule to body matchers.

I also had a look at: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit where maxArrayLike / minArrayLike looks promising, but I don't know how I can apply this to my case.

---

Edit2:

Now I have a very cool PactDslWithProvider as following:

```
    return builder.given("Genereller Test").uponReceiving("Feed soll Eintraege enthalten").path(SERVICEPATH)
            .query(query).method(METHOD_GET).headers(ACCEPT, REQ_ACCEPT).willRespondWith().status(200)
            .matchHeader(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, RESP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE_REGEX)
            .body(responseBody)
            .matchBody(new PactDslXmlNodeMatcher().node("feed").minMaxType(minNumberNodesInFeed, maxNumberNodesInFeed))
            .toPact();
```

The method "minMaxType" adds a MinMaxTypeMatcher to the body-category with the path of the node.
The actual behaviour of this:
It matches type, min and max of the most inner nodes of `$.feed`. Like:  `$.feed.0.title`, `$.feed.1.link`, ..., `$.feed.6.entry.0.title`

**But what I actually want is to verify that `$.feed` has a min and a max number of subnodes. How can I achieve that?**

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I added some information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use Pact to do a functional test, rather than a contract test. Generally speaking, you shouldn't be writing tests that care about how many items there are in an array. Have a read of these two links and let me know how you go.

- https://docs.pact.io/best-practices/consumer#use-pact-for-contract-testing-not-functional-testing-of-the-provider
- https://docs.pact.io/best-practices/consumer/contract-tests-vs-functional-tests

Also, join us on slack.pact.io if you haven't already.

Comment: The thing is... As customer I call an URL of a feed, specifiy a limit of entries and some other things. I want to achieve that it's sure that when the provider changes something about which parameters I can give via URL or the behaviour in some way, my test fails.
At my point of view that forces me to specify what I expect when I give parameters via URL.
That may be too functional, but in my view tests on the provider side don't really make sure I as consumer know about how the API works and especially do not verify that I consumer get as consumer what I expect to get.

Comment: I think in understand your problem. Does this address it? https://docs.pact.io/best-practices/provider/using-provider-states-effectively